# Flutter TextField disables the GestureDetector to recieve the onTap event

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, flutter-textformfield

I have a `TextField` as the child of a `GestureDetector`. When I tap on the TextField, it gains focus and shows the keyboard on the screen which is normal. But I also want to call the `onTap` function of the `GestureDetector`, but it does not work. Other functions, such as `onPanDown` and `onDoubleTap` of the `GestureDetector` works fine but `onTap` doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test Page')),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {   // <------- Doesn't work
          print('onTap called!');
        },
        onPanDown: (details) {   // <------- Works fine
          print('onPanDown called!');
        },
        onDoubleTap: () {   // <------- Works fine
          print('onDoubleTap called!');
        },
        child: const TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write something...'),
          minLines: 15,
          maxLines: 15,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How to solve this problem and also call the `onTap` function of the `GestureDetector`? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I want exactly the `onTap` to be called! For example, the `onPanDown` almost works for me, but when the `TextField` is filled with text and when I scroll the `TextField`, the `onPanDown` is also called, which is not something I want.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are the `onTap:` could be misinterpreted with all those activities involved in opening the Keyboard, typing and e.t.c. If possible try using the `onTap:` inside the TextField like so:

```
...
const TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write something...'),
          minLines: 15,
          onTap:(){},//<==Try this
          maxLines: 15,
        ),
```

Comment: This is correct. But you know what, the problem that occurred to me is not actually with the `TextField` itself, but with another type of `TextField` called `QuillEditor` from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill package. It's almost like `TextField`, but with rich text capabilities. It doesn't have an `onTap` callback as the `TextField` has. 
For simplicity, the question was about `TextField` but I didn't notice that the `TextField` has an `onTap` callback, whereas the `QuillEditor` does not have it.
Could you suggest a solution for this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => log("Outer On onTap"),
            ),
            TextField(
              onTap: () => log("Inner On onTap"),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Write something..."),
              minLines: 15,
              maxLines: 15,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct. But you know what, the problem that occurred to me is not actually with the `TextField` itself, but with another type of `TextField` called `QuillEditor` from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill package. It's almost like `TextField`, but with rich text capabilities. It doesn't have an `onTap` callback as the `TextField` has. 
For simplicity, the question was about `TextField` but I didn't notice that the `TextField` has an `onTap` callback, whereas the `QuillEditor` does not have it.
Could you suggest a solution for this specific case?